# Trying to secure by multiple IPs, Symfony 2.3.9 not working

Tags: security, symfony, routes, ip

I am trying to secure by IP a part of my application using Symfony 2.3.9. It works for a single IP however I want to have multiple IPs but when I try to use `ips: [127.0.0.1, ::1]` I get an error. In the documentation it says that I can use that in symfony 2.3.

```
access_control:

- { path: ^/api/external/.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: [127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.166] }
- { path: ^/api/external/.*, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception '...\InvalidConfigurationException' with message 'Unrecognized options "ips" under "security.access_control.0"' in ...
```

I am also using `JMSSecurityExtraBundle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug caused by `JMSSecurityExtraBundle`:

https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/issues/146

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing ^/api/external/.* with ^/api/external